# Don't wait for subprocesses, but check for returncode later on

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, return-code

I'm working on a script that runs a number of subprocesses. The script should be able to run them all, then check in a loop if they're done.

Not start one, wait for it to finish, then start the next.

For example:

```
sp1 = subprocess.Popen(["sleep 60", shell=True)
sp2 = subprocess.Popen(["sleep 10", shell=True)
sp3 = subprocess.Popen(["sleep 80", shell=True)

sp1_done = False
sp2_done = False
sp3_done = False
while not sp1_done and not sp2_done and not sp3_done:
    if sp1.returncode and not sp1_done:
        print("sp1 done")
        sp1_done = True
    if sp2.returncode and not sp2_done:
        print("sp2 done")
        sp2_done = True
    if sp3.returncode and not sp3_done:
        print("sp3 done")
        sp3_done = True

print("all done")
```

I've read that one can access the error code of the subprocess with

`sp1_data = sp1.communicate()[0]` and then with

`returncode = sp1.returncode`

But like this, the script waits for `sp1` to finish.

How can I run multiple subprocesses, not wait for them to finish, but check if they're done (e.g. by checking the return code)?

Comment: you could create 1 thread per process and run `subprocess.Popen` from there. Nice amiga pic btw.

Comment: I've no experience with Python threading, but I'll look into it, thanks man! haha - yeah! It's a beauty!

Comment: To elaborate on what Jean-François Fabre said, try using the built in "thread" library (I actually think it's "_thread" in Python 3).  You use thread.start_new to start a new thread.  It's a very simple library for a complex concept.  Try Googling "python thread documentation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the poll method for each subprocess started.  And check returncode is not None:

```
 while ....  # as written
     sp1.poll()
     sp2.poll()
     sp3.poll()
     if sp1.returncode is not None and not sp1_done:
          .... # as written
     ... # as written
```

Comment: Works as intended! But I'll have to consider implementing threads, as others suggested.